# How to get Intel Wireless-Ac 9260 to work with Z370 Motherboard on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

- Intel Wireless-Ac 9260
- fenvi Desktop Wireless Network M.2(NGFF) WiFi Card to PCIe 1X Adapter Converter
- Gigabyte Z370XP SLI
- Windows 10 x64
- Intel AC 9260WiFi - 21.20.0_Driver64_Win10
- Intel AC 9260BT - 21.20.0_64_Win10

Everything looks good in the device manager but the WiFi icon in the tray is replaced by the globe and no Wireless networks are detected as if the wireless adapter is not present.

Any ideas how to get this Intel Wireless-Ac 9260 adapter to work with the Z370 motherboard under Windows 10?

[image: Device Manager]

[image: System Tray]

Comment: What PCIe slot do you have it installed in?  Please provide a screenshot of the properties of the device via Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out these laptop WiFi cards have two super tiny antenna connectors.

Fenvi adapter "instructions" were just some pictures so I missed that but after connecting two tiny wires to these connectors on the card the card picked up the signal and I was able to connect...

In this picture below you can see one of the wires connected to the card and what the other one looks like.

[image]